# how to make an animation in matlab

Tags: matlab, animation, audio

Would it be possible to make an animation with Matlab that is triggered by an audio signal?
I would like to read an audio signal and based on the amplitude of the signal I would like to enlarge a circle that is (pre) drawn in a figure.

To start (upon suggestion of Randall) the problem could be simplified:

A circle in a figure should increase the diameter based on a loudness input (it could be represented at first glance by a sinusoidal function, i.e. the circle becomes smaller between pi/2 and 3 pi/2 and it should become bigger between 3 pi/2 and  5pi/2).

Thanks

Comment: Are you reading the audio signal from a file or in real time from a sound input device, like a microphone?

Comment: If it is possible to read it real time via the mic input would be awesome...anyway to start I could also use an audio file stored in the computer...

Comment: I recommend breaking up the problem into two pieces. One animates the circle in a figure based on a loudness input. The other is an envelope follower to produce that loudness signal. The initial envelope follower would use a wave file. A subsequent one would use a microphone.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree! I will modify the question and narrow it to the first part

Comment: Just to clarify, the circle is a representation of the loudest the signal has been in the past, not its current loudness value, right? In other words, the circle only gets bigger, never smaller? A high water mark, so to speak.

Comment: Thanks for this question. Actually the circle should represent the current loudness, i.e. if it increases the circle should become bigger, smaller if the loudness decreases. Instead of a ramp function a gaussian might be more  suitable..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76093/discussion-between-randall-cook-and-gabboshow).